# linqdatasource: Databind from another project

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I have a solution "Foo" with 2 projects. "FooCore" and "FooWeb" where FooCore peoject contains the FooDatacontext in namespace Foo.FooCore.Core.Domain . How can bind the datacontext with linqdatasource in FooWeb project in aspx page. Is this possible by doing "<% Import Namespace="Foo.FooCore.Core.Domain"%>" in that aspx page? I hope I able to explain my problem.
Hope for a good simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you project "FooWeb" have a reference to "FooCore" then add your linqdatasource and specify the ContextTypeName="Foo.FooCore.Core.Domain.FooDatacontext "